# java generics and the addAll method

Tags: java, generics, collections

What is the correct type of argument to the addAll(..) method in Java collections? If I do something like this:

```
List<? extends Map<String, Object[]>> currentList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object[]>>();
Collection<HashMap<String, Object[]>> addAll = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object[]>>();
// add some hashmaps to the list..
currentList.addAll(addAll);
```

I understand I need to initialize both variables. However, I get a compilation error (from eclipse):

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Object[]>>) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Object[]>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ? extends 
     Map<String,Object[]>>)
    - The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Object[]>>) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Object[]>> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (Collection<HashMap<String,Object[]>>)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit to show your declarations for both 'currentList' and 'newElements'?

Comment: I think 'newElements' is supposed to be 'addAll'  I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only insert instances of `T` into a `List<T>`.

The type `List<? extends Map<X,Y>>` stands for a list of an *unknown* type `T` which `extends Map<X,Y>`. For instance, it could stand for a `List<LinkedHashMap<X,Y>>`. Obviously, you may not insert an ordinary `HashMap<X,Y>` into such a list.

You probably want:

```
List<Map<String, Object[]>> currentList;
```

Or if you want to be really flexible you could do:

```
List<? super Map<String, Object[]>> currentList;
```

Which would allow you to do crazy things like:

```
currentList = new ArrayList<Map<? super String, ? extends Object[]>>();
```

You might also wish to read Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ, particularly [the section about wildcards](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard%20instantiation?).

Answer (score 10):

Replace `extends` by `super`.

The `addAll()` itself takes an `? extends T` argument and that won't work when `T` is `? extends Map<K, V>`. With the change it will become effectively `? extends ? super Map<K, V>`.

But still, better is just to remove that `? extends` (or `? super`). It's superfluous in this particular case. Just use `List<Map<String, Object[]>>`. The `addAll()` will then effectively take `? extends Map<String, Object[]>>`.

Comment: why even declare the `currentList` as `List<? super Map<String, Object[]>>`, and not just `List<Map<String, Object[]>>` ? this part of his code seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @matt: That's also what I said in last paragraph :)

Answer (score 9):

just remember:

for `<? extends ...>`, you cannot put things (except null) into it

for `<? super ...>`, you cannot get things (except Object) out of it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call any method with generic attributes on such a list.  Basically, what `? extends Foo` says is "something that extends `Foo`", but you don't know what that something is.  When that type is returned, you can say that returned value is `Foo` or some subtype.  But for any given value you cannot that it matches `? extends Foo` generic.

In short: you need to change `currentList` declaration *or* cast it to `List` (*without* generics) and live with a warning or (if you know what you are doing) suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically boils down to this:

```
public static <T extends Collection<?>> void foo(T t) {
T x = null;
x.addAll(t);
}
```

This will fail with essentially the same error as you describe.  Try something along these lines to fix it.

```
public static <T extends Collection<Y>, Y> void foo(T t) {
T x = null;
x.addAll(t);
}
```

Alternatively, in your example above you could change

```
List<? extends Map<String, Object[]>> currentList;
```

to

```
List<Map<String, Object[]>> currentList;
```

Generics gets hairy pretty quickly if you try to start passing around unspecified types.